# How to create a parallax effect in html for a fixed div

Tags: html, css

I have created a html page with a fixed sidebar which also have a background image. I'm trying to bring a parallax effect into the background image but I simply can't. I tried changing the background-attachment into fixed and scroll, but as the div is fixed parallax effect just won't work for me. Please find me a solution. 
Here's my css code.

```
.header{
    background-image: url("../images/8.jpg");
    background-attachment:scroll;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Asap Condensed';
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  }
```

Comment: You should probably use Javascript for an actual parallax effect (I assume you're looking to get different scrolling speeds). If you really don't want to use any you can take a look at this tutorial for a pure css Parallax effect:
http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Keep in mind that this tutorial is kind of experimental, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) using the `background-attachment: fixed;` technique:

```
<style>
.parallax { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");

    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 500px; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
</style>

<!-- Container element -->
<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but as I said the div is fixed and giving the property of background-attachment:fixed does not make a parallax effect in the code that I have uploaded in the question.

Comment: No, it won't in the code you have uploaded, but you should be able to place it inside another div and only give the parallax effect to one div.